# .Net Setup issue

Tags: .net

I used vs2010 to create a project that uses framework 2.0.
I can't use a newer framework.
I created a setup project for it, and when I try to install it on the server, it's asking to install framework 4.0. I can't install it.
Is it possible to fix this somehow? Can I change the setup program framework to 2.0?

Thanks.

Comment: why can't you 'use a newer framework'?

Comment: production server. no big changes allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the setup by using the prerequisite.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y(v=vs.80).aspx

You also have to choose wich runtime to use for the Programm and Setup.
This is in the Tab for the Conditions in your Setup Project.
see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7e70ac3.aspx

Comment: I didn't get the 2nd part; "You also have to..."

Comment: The Setup Checks some components on the Target Machine. This can be configured unter the Conditions Tab for the Setup. (Click right on the Setupproject and choose the View) There should be a check for the .NET Runtime which has to be changed to 2.0